# How can I process many micro-CT images by using Julia language?

Tags: image-processing, julia, x-ray

I have 1000 jpg images and I need to make them into a stl file so It can be printed in 3D.

I'd like to do it in Julia since it's a language I'm familiar with. Maybe there's libraries for that in another language... I don't know.

Any suggestions or ideas will be wellcome.

Thanks!

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/post/The_best_way_to_convert_Stack_of_CT_images_to_STL_file

Comment: The title is a bit misleading. You're not doing image-processing, this is just a file format question.

Answer (score 0):

You can always search [JuliaObserver](https://juliaobserver.com/packages) for relevant packages. It looks like the first hit, https://github.com/mohamed82008/VTKDataIO.jl, might do what you need?